# Using the addDiv(command) in R from quantstrat/blotter

Tags: r, quantmod, quantitative-finance, quantstrat, blotter

What is the format for using the addDiv command in R? I know how to use the function as far as inputs go, but I can't figure out where it should be placed beyond a general idea. Do I place it after where I instantiate the portfolio? Below is the help article R provides:

> Add cash dividend transactions to a portfolio.
>
> #### Description
>
> Adding a cash dividend does not affect position quantity, like a split
>   would.
>
> #### Usage
>
> ```
> addDiv(Portfolio, Symbol, TxnDate, DivPerShare, ..., TxnFees = 0,  
>        ConMult = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
> ```
>
> #### Arguments
>
> `Portfolio`    A portfolio name that points to a portfolio object
>   structured with `initPortf`.
>
> `Symbol`   An instrument identifier for a symbol included in the
>   portfolio, e.g., IBM.
>
> `TxnDate`  Transaction date as ISO 8601, e.g., '2008-09-01' or
>   '2010-01-05 09:54:23.12345'.
>
> `DivPerShare`  The amount of the cash dividend paid per share or per
>   unit quantity.
>
> `TxnFees`  Fees associated with the transaction, e.g. commissions. See
>   Details.
>
> `ConMult`  Contract or instrument multiplier for the Symbol if it is not
>   defined in an instrument specification.
>
> `verbose`  If `TRUE` (default) the function prints the elements of the
>   transaction in a line to the screen, e.g., "2007-01-08 IBM 50 @ 77.6".
>   Suppress using `FALSE`.
>
> `...`  Any other passthrough parameters.
>
> #### Note
>
> **# TODO add TxnTypes to $txn table
>
> **# TODO add AsOfDate****

Comment: I have not used it myself, but "add cash divident transactions to a portfolio" suggests that you should do it after creating a portfolio as opposed to before. Otherwise, I would guess that you add it wherever makes sense in terms of your code.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how to use it, which is based on `demo("longtrend")` from the blotter package. As you can see, it's fine if you call it after the fact, since blotter knows your position.

That said, you'll need to call it contemporaneously if you need to know your total P&L in order to make trading decisions.

```
require(blotter)
demo(longtrend, ask=FALSE)

# Add dividends from SPY
spyDiv <- getDividends("SPY", from=initDate)
for(i in 1:nrow(spyDiv)) {
  obs <- spyDiv[i,]
  addDiv("longtrend", "GSPC", index(obs), obs)
}
# Need to update portfolio, account, etc again, since
# we added new transactions
updatePortf("longtrend")
updateAcct("longtrend")
updateEndEq("longtrend")

# Plot position with dividends, calling dev.new() so
# we can compare it to the original plot from the demo.
dev.new()
chart.Posn("longtrend", "GSPC", Dates="1998::")
add_SMA(n=10, col="darkgreen", on=1)

#look at a transaction summary
getTxns(Portfolio="longtrend", Symbol="GSPC")
```